# Scheduling offline tasks according to load in Azure

Tags: azure, scheduler, job-scheduling

We have a system deployed to Azure, where we have a real-time service (always running) and several offline tasks that we need to run periodically.

We would like to use the same workers for the real-time and offline tasks, by making the offline tasks take only the resources not currently in-use by the real-time service (the load on the real-time service changes according to time-of-day, but I would prefer not to schedule on a fixed-hour basis).

I'm sure this isn't an uncommon situation but I couldn't find an existing solution to handle the load-measurement and scheduling for me.

Any thoughts or links will be very appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Any problem with scheduling? And what is the role that you are using, is it a web role or worker role or Service bus?

Comment: I use worker roles, which can carry out several operations. Some of the operations are mission-critical and some should only be executed when CPU is available. I need some "smart scheduling" that takes into account the availability of resources when scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Windows Azure Autoscaling Application Block: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892(v=pandp.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx). Using this you can identify when your application is running under low load and based on that you can initiate your tasks. Commonly this application block is used for auto scaling i.e. increasing or decreasing your instances but I don't think why it can't be used to spawn new tasks instead of autoscaling. HTH.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I would have to code custom actions but the CPU sampling and the other features are certainly helpful. I'm adding this link to the customization of WASABi: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680889(v=pandp.50).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to be said for keeping things nice and tidy from a maintenance point of view and not bundling too many things together.

That said I guess you could have your worker role spawn a thread that would monitor the activity of the role and decide when to preform its actions alongside whatever other activity the role performs already.

The main thing I would ensure is a periodical check that this thread is alive...